# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalViewController", referenced from

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Can any one tell me the meaning of this error , 
this is the details of the error log :

```
Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Holiday.app/Holiday normal i386
cd /Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/Examples/Holiday
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -L/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/Examples/Holiday/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/Examples/Holiday/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/Examples/Holiday/build/Holiday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Holiday.build/Objects-normal/i386/Holiday.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics /Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/src/build/Debug-iphoneos/libKal.a -lsqlite3 -o /Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/Examples/Holiday/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Holiday.app/Holiday

ld: warning: in /Users/Ahmed/Desktop/klazuka-Kal-b2e164c/src/build/Debug-iphoneos/libKal.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-KalViewController in HolidayAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a linker error, ensure that KalViewController is added to the current target, choose Get Info on it and go to the targets tab, ensure that the box is ticked.

Comment: sorry, I m still new in iphone development, can you tell me more details ?

Comment: Your application has a target which is basically a collection of files and settings which tell Xcode how to build you application. When you add files to your project you have to tell Xcode which target the file needs to be linked to. In your case the file isn't linked to your target so when Xcode comes to build the file, it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Kal project's settings, make sure that it is compiled for the i386 architecture.

Comment: THIS IS NOT THE ERROR, IT'S JUST A WARNING

Comment: But it is the reason for the subsequent error. Warnings are there to tell you something.